# how to print a temperature table with step taken from the user?

Tags: c++

here is my code: somehow it works but I dont know how to make the program to get the step from the user and only output the values according to the step.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    cout <<"enter the first degree in celcues :" ;
    int t1;
    cin >> t1;
    cout << "enter the second degree in celcues :" ;
    int t2;
    cin >> t2;
    cout << "enter dt :" ;
    int dt;
    cin >> dt;

    double farn;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout <<"C\tF" << endl;
    for (int i=t1; i<=t2; i++){
    
    
    farn=(1.8*i)+32;
    
        cout <<i<< "\t";
    
    cout <<farn<<endl;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = t1; i <= t2; i += dt) {` ?

Comment: OMG thank you so much <3 <3

Comment: it works... thank you dear))